# MySQL Execute fails query after insert of record on previous pass

Tags: php, mysql

This routine used to work until we moved to a much faster debian linux server.
This is a snippet of code that reads through a csv file and inserts records into a table if another record with the same manufacturers_name dosn't exist. What is happening is the first record is inserted and when another record is found the execute function fails to find the previous inserted record and adds the record instead of updating.  If I run the same routine a 2nd time without emptying the table all the records are found and only update takes place.  I thought maybe the issue was speed so I tried putting sleeps in the process but it had no affect.  Any ideas?
Thanks

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, chr(9),chr(0))) !== FALSE) {

    ****** Setup stuff here  *******
    $msql_data_array = array('manufacturers_name' => $data[$manufacturer_sn]);
    $sql = "select count(*) as total,manufacturers_id,manufacturers_name from " . TABLE_MANUFACTURERS . " where manufacturers_name = \"" . $data[$manufacturer_sn] . "\"";

    $manufacturers = $db->Execute($sql);
    if ($manufacturers->fields['total'] == 0) {  <<<<<<<<<<<< This always returns 0 even if the record was just added by the previous operation(s)
            ***** Inserts a new record ******

    } else {
            ***** Updates the current record *******
    }

]
```

Comment: Besides the above, I would like to know what $manufacturers is. If anything, the first thing when debugging why an if statement is not triggering... Check the variables. I'm pretty sure that what is being compared, is non-existent or due to this being a different version / method it most likely is returning something slightly different (if anything at all).

Comment: Show us the code for the `$db` class specifically the `Execute` method as if it ever worked it is not either raw `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: Why not define a unique index on `(manufacturers_id,manufacturers_name)` and use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... `?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a simple **.csv** import.  You could replace the PHP code with a command line MySQL call, like so:

> mysqlimport --fields-terminated-by '\t' db_name import.csv

Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html